# particle is moving uniformly along a circle

Tags: functions

Suppose a particle is moving uniformly along a circle $Y$; let $X$ be the axis of time and $x\mapsto^Fy$ be the correspondence between a moment of time $x\in X$ and the position $y=f(x) \in Y$ of the particle. Draw the graph of a function from $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to $X \times Y$.

My thoughts: X is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so just a bunch of values from $t_0$ to $\infty$. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ takes a point $t_n$ on that line and maps it to a point on a circle, $f(t_n)=y$, for some y. So $f:X \rightarrow Y$ as a graph looks like a sine wave, since it starts with 0 and is 0 again after every $2\pi$ movements of the particle along the circle. But I am out of ideas as to how the final graph $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to $X \times Y$ is supposed to look like, and for that matter how $X\times Y$ should look like. Unless I'm misunderstanding, it should be the cartesian product of a line and a circle, so ... a half open cylinder stretching to $\infty$, since t starts at 0 but can grow arbitrarily large? So by my logic the final graph should look like a sine wave, all points of which map to a half-open cylinder (if such a term even exists). Since I was asked to plot the graph, this doesn't seem realistic, so i would appreciate any comments.

Comment: Uniformly means $x \mapsto e^{i\lambda x}$? What does mean a function from $f:X \to Y$? Does it mean from $X$ to $Y$? If what I think is true, your graph is just a spiral?

Comment: @JulesBesson Yes, a function from X to Y. So something like x(t) = cos(t), y(t) = sin(t) and z(t) = t? So a parametric equation? What confused me the most in the question is $X\times Y$, since X was given as the axis of time, and Y was given as the circle. Also the domain of the map I'm supposed to draw is the actual function f:X→Y, not just the output times, as I understand it, otherwise it would just say f(X) I think?

Comment: Yes, I think it's just an error of copy paste, you must draw the graph of $f$ which is a spiral in $\mathbb{R}^3$